# python to change '|' into tab delimenated

Tags: python, genome, sequencing

I need to replace '|' into tab so that I can analyze my human annotation genomic data (200+mb). I'm a research assistant learning how to analyze/manipulate sequencing data in the easiest/simplest way so that I can replicate this on more data.

Here how my data looks like. There are ~400,000 lines of this type of data in one file.

```
       ANN=C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|OR4G4P|ENSG00000268020|transcript|ENST00000606857|unprocessed_pseudogene||n.*1414T>C|||||1414|,C|intron_variant|MODIFIER|OR4G4P|ENSG00000268020|transcript|ENST00000594647|unprocessed_pseudogene|1/1|n.20-104T>C||||||;DP=11;SS=1;VT=SNP
```

I tried to use this code to replace '|' into '\t' for several lines.

```
import csv
infile = 'Book2.xlsx'
with open(infile , 'r') as inf: 
    for line in inf:    
        w =csv.writer(inf, delimiter = '\t')
        print w
```

All I'm getting is this :

```
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x7f8beebaafc8>
```

Comment: The `csv` module cannot read and write Excel format `.xlsx` files, only  text file containing Character Separated Value. There are a number of third party modules for Python that allow processing Excel files so you will need to use one (although in theory you could write your own). Secondly, even if `csv` did support the format, your code is creating a new `csv.writer` _class instance_ for every line of the input file it reads, which is why you're getting the output shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regular expression.
Example for one line:

```
a = "ANN=C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|OR4G4P|ENSG00000268020|transcript|ENST00000606857|unprocessed_pseudogene||n.*1414T>C|||||1414|,C|intron_variant|MODIFIER|OR4G4P|ENSG00000268020|transcript|ENST00000594647|unprocessed_pseudogene|1/1|n.20-104T>C||||||;DP=11;SS=1;VT=SNP"


import re
regex= re.compile(r'\|')
regex.sub("\t",a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`print w` is just printing the brand new `csv.writer` object you created (and you probably don't mean to be creating a new writer on every loop). If you want to write to it, use [the actual `writerow` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow). There is a lot of [example code on the `csv` docs page for reading and writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples), you just need to combine them (and use an alternate dialect for each).

You're not actually using a `csv.reader`, and even if you were, your input file is `.xlsx`, which is not CSV, pipe delimited, or anything else, it's a much more complex data format (Office XML, and it's a zip file, so it looks like binary gibberish when read directly) that `csv` can't read.

Answer (score 0):

Your filename indicates excel, but for now I will assume you actually have a tsv (Tab Seperated) file and not an Excel file.  If so

```
infile = 'Book2.tsv'
of = 'Book2.csv'
with open(infile , 'r') as inf: 
    for line in inf:
         of.write(line.replace('|',','))
of.close()
```

Of course if it is Excel that's different try xlrd Udacity has some nice lessons in "Data Wrangling with MongoDB"